# How to use String.split with a text file to add to a simple array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, split

My goal is to read in a text file and add each element to a simple array (the elements are separated by a comma). The last method **readData()** is the one I can't figure out.

My code so far :

```
public class VersionChooser {

private Scanner scan;
private StockManager aManager = new StockManager("StockManager");

public VersionChooser() {
    this.scan = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void chooseVersion() {
    this.readData();
    this.runTextOption();
}

private void runTextOption() {
    StockTUI tui = new StockTUI(this.aManager);
}

public StockManager readData() {
    String fileName;
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to be used");
    fileName = this.scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fileName);
    try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File("fileName").toPath(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_16)) {
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            final String[] data = line.split(","); 
            StockRecord record = new StockRecord(data[0], Double.valueOf(data[4])); 
            this.aManager.getStockList().add(record);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }   


    return null;
}
}
```

StockRecord :

```
public class StockRecord {
private String date;
private double closingPrice;

public StockRecord(String date, double closingPrice) {
    this.date = date;
    this.closingPrice = closingPrice;
}

public String getDate() {
    return this.date;
}

public double getClosingPrice() {
    return this.closingPrice;
}
public String toString() {
    return "On " + this.date + " this stock had a closing price of $" 
            + this.closingPrice;
}
}
```

Comment: Elaboration : Each line in the file has 5 separate data points. I want to use scanner.NextLine() and String.split to pull the data needed and add it to a "StockRecord" which is another class of mine.

Comment: what does your `StockRecord` class look like? And are all the data points going to the same instance of `StockRecord` ?

Comment: This is an example of some of the lines in the text file
**9/24/2004 12:00:00 AM,18.45,19.43,18.41,18.65,6.43062E+07,**
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
**10/1/2004 12:00:00 AM,18.49,19.64,18.42,19.33,6.83976E+07,**
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
**10/8/2004 12:00:00 AM,19.59,20.47,19.2,19.53,7.90538E+07,**
It represents different stock numbers. The "|||||||" was added by me to separate them so it didn't get confusing

Comment: `String.split("[\\|]+")`?

Comment: I'm not quite clear still on what trouble you're having. You said (correctly) that you need to use `nextLine()` and `String#split`, so what part are you uncertain about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1 : Read the file line by line.

Step2: Split the line by ","

Step3 : Construct the String[] to StockRecord.

```
try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File("stock.txt").toPath(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        List<StockRecord> stocks = new ArrayList<StockRecord>();
                    br.readLine() ; // to avoid first line
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) { // first step
            final String[] data = line.split(",");       // second step
            StockRecord record = new StockRecord(data[0], Double.valueOf(data[1]));
            stocks.add(record);    // third step
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your stockRecord doesn't has all records. and for demo purpose i did assumed 2 element is closing price . change accordingly

Comment: Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume ,Moving Average 50
   This is the order of the numbers. Thank you, What I needed to do was only pull out the date and closing price. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: then change data[1] to data[4] since your closing is 4th element in array ( array starts with 0)

Comment: I keep getting an error whenever I type in console what file to choose. I have another class called StockManager that holds the arraylist (I declared it at the top of VersionChooser) would I need to use that to add the data?

Comment: post your updated code and what is your input . yes if you have method to get ArrayList from StockManager. then use that like aManager.getStockList().add(record)

Comment: I posted the new code for readData(). The file name is "AppleStock.txt" and I've tried to type in AppleStocks and AppleStocks.txt but it give me errors both times

Comment: @user3241721 change new File("fileName") to new File(fileName) . you have to type complete path like . c:\\projects\\AppleStocks.txt  ( just sample dont copy paste)

Comment: Getting closer. I keep getting an error and it's sending me back to this line of code "StockRecord record = new StockRecord(data[0], Double.valueOf(data[4])); "

Comment: My bad. Change StandardCharsets.UTF_16 to StandardCharsets.UTF_8 . if any error please provide the error ( exception trace)

Comment: I get the same error as before. It always points to this line "             StockRecord record = new StockRecord(data[0], Double.valueOf(data[4])); " The error is this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Close"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at package..controller.VersionChooser.readData(VersionChooser.java:71)
 at package.controller.VersionChooser.chooseVersion(VersionChooser.java:47)
 at package.controller.StockDriver.main(StockDriver.java:17)

Comment: I prepared sample file and executed. it went well.My assumption is each record separated by line. add System.out.println(line); before spilt. error showing , you are trying to converting into double which is not double. but as per your format it should be double

Comment: Ok, I now know that it can open the file. It lists "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume ,Moving Average 50" Which is the first line, but right after that it gives me this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Close""

Comment: I don't know what 'input string: close" is. Is it when you don't close the file after you use it in the program?

Comment: Are you saying your first line has text like that ? then you need to skip the first line. see my update ( before for loop)

Comment: My god... You are great. It works! All the options work, and it works great. Thank you so much!